# Gradient with Shape

Tags: html, css, gradient, linear-gradients

I'm trying to do a gradient on a button but I can't make it have the same gradient as the other part of the button.
I tried adding a gradient inside a gradient but it doesn't seems to work and can't find a solution for it.
This the code I'm using:

```css
button{
  color: white;
  padding: 3px 3px 3px 0px;
  border: 0px;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: right;
  background: linear-gradient(50deg , transparent 50%, rgb(149, 151, 155) 0%) left no-repeat, linear-gradient(rgb(200, 205, 212), rgb(149, 151, 155)) 30px 0 no-repeat;
  background-size: 30px 100%, 100% 100%;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<button>Meet the Team</button>
```

Is there a way to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a skew transformation on a pseudo element where you apply the gradient. Since it's a top/bottom direction, the gradient will not get affected by the skewing

```css
button{
  color: white;
  padding: 3px 3px 3px 0px;
  border: 0px;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: right;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow:hidden;
  background:none;
  z-index:0;
}
button::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  transform-origin:top;
  transform:skewX(50deg);
  background:linear-gradient(rgb(200, 205, 212), rgb(149, 151, 155));
}
```

```html
<button>Meet the Team</button>
```

For another direction, you may need to adjust the degree of the gradient:

```css
button{
  color: white;
  padding: 3px 3px 3px 0px;
  border: 0px;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: right;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow:hidden;
  background:none;
  z-index:0;
}
button::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  transform-origin:top;
  transform:skewX(50deg);
  background:linear-gradient(-50deg,purple,red);
}
```

```html
<button>Meet the Team</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

That's because you are already using the linear-gradient property as a trick to create a triangle end on your button.

You can't use the same property multiple times. If you want a triangle end, maybe stick with flat color on your button.